# Adding a product term

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

[image]

I have a linear regression model with the outcome variable **CoC** (continuous variable). Independent variables, two hormones(H1 and H2) and a moderator Age. All continuous variables.

1. Can I simply add both the product terms with hormones and age **( H1*Age and H2*age)** or have to follow some criteria or add them one by one?
2. In the following regression output with both product terms, beta coef and SE of **H2*age** is too low. Is it correct or does it simply means there is no linear relationship?

Comment: What do you mean by adding H1_Age and H2_Age?

Comment: H1*Age (H1 multiplied by Age) and H2*Age (H2 multiplied by Age). the two product terms. SPSS does not accept * (asterisk) in labels, so it has ( _ ) in label.

Comment: I understand what the terms mean, I'm just asking what you are adding them for? As in you are trying to sum up a linear equation?

Comment: Yes, adding these product terms. not sure if I can Add them both or add them  stepwise. Do I have to check the individual significance of the term with outcome variable and then add. Not sure what is the criteria to follow.

Comment: I added H1, H2, and Age to the multiple regression model which was not significant. Adding the product terms makes it significant.